# Windows Phone 7 - Push Tile Notification: Clear pushed tile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Thanks to many of you, I've finally gotten a handle on how to push Toast and Title notifications.  Now that I have an updated Title pushed to the phone, how do I clear it?

I see that there is a .UnbindToShellTile();

Right now that is causing an exception, but I might not be putting it in the correct place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can raise a tile notification with the image you want to return to and pass the count as 0 to clear that if you sent one.

From [Types of Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941124%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

*"The background image will never revert to a previous version after it has been successfully updated, unless a previous background image is sent again with a push notification."*

and

*"if a Count value is already displayed in the Tile, you must send a value of 0 to clear the Count image and value from the Tile."*

Answer (score 0):

Waht did work for me on the phone (Mango) for clearing the counter:

```
    var appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
    if (appTile == null) return; //Don't create...just update

    appTile.Update(new StandardTileData(){BackTitle = "", BackContent="", Count=0});
```